# Android XmlPullParser Загрузка с URL

Tags: android, xml

Подскажите, как спарсить файл. Мой код выдает ошибку при загрузке xml документа

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ListView lvInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        URL input = new URL("http://atelier76.ru/contacts.xml");
        parser.setInput(input.openStream(), null);

        while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equals("contact")) {
                list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + " "
                        + parser.getAttributeValue(1) + "\n"
                        + parser.getAttributeValue(2));
            }
            parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Ошибка при загрузке XML-документа: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lvInfo.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Мой магический шар утверждает что у вас NOMTE (`NetworkOnMainThreadException`) на строке

> parser.setInput(input.openStream(), null);

или

> while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

или

> if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG

Решается это как и следует из ошибки выносом работы с сетью в отдельный поток.

Например так (хотя способов много - гугл в помощь):

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //тут другой, не UI поток. Тут можно в сеть залезть
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: @МаксФадеев, см. обновлённый ответ. И в следующий раз указывайте тип ошибки и строку где падает. Без этого помочь почти всегда невозможно.

Comment: Простите нуба, я не понимаю как использовать Ваш код, мои варианты не подходят. Не могли бы Вы на основе моего кода показать? (

Comment: @МаксФадеев, просто поместите то, что у вас в try-catch вместо коммента в моём коде.. И установку и создание адаптера туда же.

Comment: Вот что у меня в этом случае  http://hkar.ru/HwTC   Не может реализовать метод makeText и Vareable "list" ais accessed from within inner class

Comment: Все получилось, большое спасибо!

Comment: @МаксФадеев, если один из ответов решает заявленную в вопросе проблему, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на "галочку" слева от тела ответа, а также проголосовать за него стрелочкой там же.